# SharePoint 2013 and ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sharepoint-2013

I would like to use ASP.NET WebApi inside a SharePoint 2013 farm solution.

I know it is not supported out-of-the-box, but I found  [SignalR can be run by means of a simple HttpModule](http://melcher.it/2012/12/signalr-in-sharepoint-2013-the-real-time-web-is-coming/), so I was wondering whether a similar appoach could be used.

Thanks in advance,
Rich

**UPDATE June 2013**

Made it working by reworking the HTTP Module shown in the mentioned post:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "kms2013/api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { }
            );
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new SPAssemblyResolver());

HostingEnvironment.RegisterVirtualPathProvider(new WebAPIVirtualPathProvider());
```

**SPAssemblyResolver**

```
public class SPAssemblyResolver : IAssembliesResolver
{
    public ICollection<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
    {
        return new List<Assembly> { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() };
    }
}
```

**WebAPIVirtualPathProvider**

Same as SignalRVirtualPathProvider shown in the post.

**NEW ISSUE**

The only problem with this approach is *ScriptResource.axd* and *WebResource.axd* now break when SP references them in a page. I tried to add an ignore route:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route("{resource}.axd", new StopRoutingHandler()));
```

But I keep getting *401 Unauthorized*. Removing the module clears the error, so I guess we're still lacking one last piece of the puzzle.

Comment: I assume you have to adjust the Virtual Path Provider, see an example here: https://spsignalr.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MaxMelcher.SPSignalR/SignalRVirtualPathProvider.cs

Comment: Fine, the VPP implementation you suggested traps all the missing cases and everything's working now.

Previously, _DirectoryExists_ yield various kind of errors when lacking _virtualDir.Contains("my/api/path")_, ranging from SharePoint JS errors, broken search, etc..

Comment: I'm trying to do the same and I'm almost there, but I get an error because it can't find the Controller. Deploying only the webapi project it works fine, but inside SP it breaks. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the same approach should work.

Create a web api project and check the app init part - then follow my blog post you referenced already.

Btw: Ask at sharepoint.stackexchange.com - maybe someone has a better solution.

Comment: Finally got time to give it a try, and actually saw some results. Module OFF -> 404 Not Found; Module ON -> 401 Unauthorized. Still have to wonder why, but it looks like we need to setup SharePoint security with WebApi

Comment: Doubt it, check the iis log for the exact error code, e.g 401.1

Comment: Fine, got it working :-) I will post an explanation ASAP. Thanks BTW!

Comment: @MaxMelcher - When you see thses kinds of questions flag them for moderator attention so the mods can migrate them to SharePoint.StachExchange.

Comment: Why? Its a cross-technology question. Its valid here imho!